# geolocation not working anymore on ANY of my browsers

Tags: web-applications, mobile, geolocation

http://benwerd.com/lab/geo.php

geolocation was working fine, then about 2 weeks ago it stopped. It prompts me, I say allow, and it says it can't get my location.

I doubt everyone is having the same issue, but what can it be? I've rebooted, and that didn't do anything.

I have a mobile web application that i'm working on and it makes it impossible to develop.

## **UPDATE**

It works fine on other computers... It's just my development one that does not work on ANY BROWSER.

## UPDATE #2:

Okay... well It must have something to do with IP/DNS looup or something because If i VPN into my house network, it works fine on the same local computer it was not working on. The only thing that has changed is my IP.

So something must have changed on my work's network that doesn't allow for my IP to be located.

Still interested in an answer that might explain in more detail what might cause this.

Comment: Have you tried switching it off and on again? :) At least the page worked for me...

No seriously, does this happen in all browsers or only in certain ones? Does this happen in different places (e.g. work computer and home computer)? Does this happen with different network setups (e.g. on your mobile or via WiFi at home)? I would start to narrow the error down this way.

Comment: @j0nes It works fine on other computers... It's just my development one that does not work on ANY BROWSER.

Comment: @j0nes how do I turn it off and on? I'm on a desktop, no wifi.

Comment: You can switch geolocation off and on in each browser and/or clear the browser cache:
http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142065
http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/geolocation/

Comment: @j0nes Please see my second update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your two updates, I think your ISP may have simply changed its IP ranges or they might have been deleted from the Geolocation Provider. Here is a description on how Geolocation works in Firefox (other browsers should behave similar):

> When you visit a location-aware website, Firefox will ask you if you
>   want to share your location. If you consent, Firefox gathers
>   information about **nearby wireless access points and your computer’s IP
>   address**. Then Firefox sends this information to the default
>   geolocation service provider, Google Location Services, to get an
>   estimate of your location. That location estimate is then shared with
>   the requesting website.
>   http://www.mozilla.org/en/firefox/geolocation/

I am not sure which IP database Google Location Services uses, I would assume they have an internal one available. For other providers, you can submit your IP and/or IP range to their database. If your new IP get available in the underlying database, Geolocation should work again.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm adding to this post 7 months after the last entry, but wanted to add that I experienced the same problem. My js which included calls to navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition stopped working as well as all website examples of the geolocation api. They were failing on all of my PCs and in FF, Opera, and Chrome. After reading the reference to possible ties to IP, I shut my router off, waited 5 minutes and restarted my router and everything worked again. I don't know if my DSL IP was updated or not...but everything is now working.